# How to know if it's a compound noun or a described noun?

Tags: grammar, compound-nouns

This is the problem:

> As you can see from ____ in Table 1.3, we can expect lower profits
> this quarter. Hopefully we'll be able to turn it around over the
> summer.
>
> Options:
>
> A) the figures highlighted
>
> B) the highlighting figures
>
> C) the highlight figures

I'm thinking whether the option B) is a compound noun or not. Suppose I replace the blank in the middle of the sentence with "something", so it'll say **As you can see something in Table 1.3** .... that means *there's something in the Table* and it makes sense to me if it refers to specific *highlighting figures*, but I have doubt with the option A) too, if I add "that" between figures and highlighted. It will be **... the figures *that* highlighted in Table 1.3...** which also makes sense to me. It's like thinking about a thing and that thing is described after it's mentioned.

So, what do you think is more appropriate? Could you also explain the reason? Thanks!

Comment: A) is correct, but none of your suggestions are 'compound nouns', which are single words, sometimes hyphenated. A)-C) are head+modifier syntactic constructions, though B)-C) are wrong. An equally good alternant to A) is "the highlighted figures".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct answer. However *"a) the figures highlighted"* is the closest and I would pick that if I had no alternative.

As you can see from the highlighted figures in Table 1.3,

As you can see from the figures that have been highlighted in Table 1.3,

As you can see from the figures, highlighted, in Table 1.3,

---

Note *the highlighting figure*; and *the highlight figures*; cannot be used because the tenses are incorrect.

---

**highlight: verb** [ T ]:** to mark text on paper** or a computer screen with a colour to emphasize it: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highlight?q=highlighted)

Comment: I took this question from british council test by the way sir, so there must be an answer. About the a) option, as I mentioned before, is it a described noun? I remember a bit I've studied about using that/which/who/whom and also a special case to omit one of them (e.g. omitting **that**). Is this a case that I'm talking about sir?

Comment: Well I am surprised it is a British council test In my opinion all the answers are incorrect. However I admit that usage defines the dictionary not the other way round. I believe figures are symbols; you do not extract data from symbols you extract data from numbers and similar sources. The same as you can read words not letters. To answer your questions. No I do not consider it a compound noun. The figures have been highlighted not figures that highlighted.